# Include JfreeChart graph and calculation results on the same JSP webpage

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jfreechart

I have a servlet that performs some calculations based on the form data submitted by the user.

I would like to plot in a chart the entered input values along with the calculation results which is displayed as text on the same webpage.

I can create the graph with JFreeChart, but it overwrites the form page if I'm using it with OutputStream. If I store the image and trying to link the URL in the JSP, the chart is not displayed. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Here is my servlet that reads different weight parameters submitted from the browser and creates the chart with OutputStream:

```
@WebServlet(name = "resultServlet", urlPatterns = {"/results"})
public class resultServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try { 

     List<Double> weightsList = new ArrayList<Double>();
     int listpos = 0;

     DefaultPieDataset myServletPieChart = new DefaultPieDataset();

         double w1 = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("w1"));
         myServletPieChart.setValue("WEIGHTONE", w1);
         weightsList.add(listpos, w1); 
         listpos++;
         double w2 = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("w2"));
         myServletPieChart.setValue("WEIGHTTWO", w2);
         weightsList.add(listpos, w2); 
         listpos++;
         double w3 = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("w3"));
         myServletPieChart.setValue("WEIGHTTHREE", w3);
         weightsList.add(listpos, w3); 
         listpos++;
         double w4 = Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("w4"));
         myServletPieChart.setValue("WEIGHTFOUR", w4);
         weightsList.add(listpos, w4); 

         request.setAttribute("WeightSel", weightsList);  //list of selected weights
         request.setAttribute("WeightSum", weightSum(weightsList)); //sum of selected weights
         request.setAttribute("CalcResult", resultCalculator(weightsList)); //result of some calculations performed on selected weights

         // set piechart attributes

         JFreeChart inputWeightsPie = ChartFactory.createPieChart("Selected Weights",myServletPieChart,true,true,false);
         response.setContentType("image/png"); /* Set the HTTP Response Type */

         OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
         ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, inputWeightsPie, 400, 300);/* Write the data to the output stream */
         //or alternatively:
         // ImageIO.write(inputWeightsPie.createBufferedImage(400, 300), "png", out);
         out.close();

        }


    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "value must be a number!"); 
    }
    ServletContext ctx = this.getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ctx.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current (main) servlet should be used for html content only.
Create separate servlet for the chart (where you can use `writeChartAsPNG`).
On JSP page use it as
`<img src="servChart?w1=100&w2=200">` with your parameters.

**UPDATE**
Also you can do chart calculation in the same servlet. Put `JFreeChart` object into session.
And in `servChart?name=myChart` servlet get JFreeChart (by attribute name) from the session and output as bytes.

Comment: Ok, I wrote the chart part in a completely separate servlet, chartServlet.java. The problem is that the main servlet is called from the jsp form submission first, and it performs the calculations, then display the results. But I need the same form data on the ChartServlet as well (and later the calculation results as well to be plotted). I wonder how I can use those parameters on the separate ChartServlet as well? Also, on the JSP page Im not sure how I should include all this at the end (e.g. servChart in your text would refer to the link of the new ChartServlet?) Thanks for help

Comment: So I tried to give some time to have a research on how to make JSP sessions, but I cannot really see how to do it in this case. (Im anyway a beginner with JSP-servlets, but I got lost with the sessions even more) Lets say this is what is going on so far: In index.jsp: FORM with action="mainServlet" user set w1,w2..w4 values, SUBMIT-->mainServlet called: doPost reads w1,w2..w4;performs some calc; write results to parameters<--index.jsp: print results below the form(c:out); and here is where I would need a piechart of the form's w1, w2..w4 values, and another graph of the calculation results.

Comment: Then in case of session, I guess I need to call another jsp file, e.g. chartplot.jsp within the the form where w1,w2...w4 values are submitted? Is it possible to have 2 actions for one form (i.e. call the mainservlet and chartplot.jsp as well)?

Comment: @user2718897 As I understand user submits parameters w1...w4, so after you get `JFreeChart inputWeightsPie` in the servlet, do session.setAttribute("myChart ",inputWeightsPie); and forward to your normal jsp. Then in jsp you have <img src="servChart?name=myChart"> where in this servlet you get (JFreeChart) session.getAttribute(request.getParameter("myChart")); and output bytes.